# Input field appearing on default checked select box

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I'm working on a form where we have the option to assign products to an object or in this case an user. Depending on the values given in our database that is retrieved and used in the code this user may have one of these specific product by default.

```
if($Pants=="1"){
   echo "<input type='checkbox' onclick='PantsInput(this);' checked>Pants<br>";
}
else {
   echo "<input type='checkbox'> Pants<br>";
}
```

There's a little JavaScript that creates a text input field if the checkbox is selected. It works, but ONLY if I go ahead and select it manually.

What I am trying to accomplish is for the script to recognize if the checkbox is already checked or not. It should still be possible to do it manually, but it would be great for the fields to appear on load if the checkbox is already checked.

Here's the script:

```
function PantsInput(cbox) {
      if (cbox.checked) {
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        input.value = "1";
        input.name = "AmountPants"
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.id = cbox.name;
        div.innerHTML = "Amount of pants: ";
        div.appendChild(input);
        document.getElementById("pantsinput").appendChild(div);
      } else {
        document.getElementById(cbox.name).remove();
      }
    }
```

Here's a JSFiddle that shows what I am struggling with:
https://jsfiddle.net/orqweyzc/

The box is already checked but the field will only appear if you go ahead and uncheck and check it again yourself. I've tried some different DOM Events, but can't seem to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
  
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    
    switch (inputs[i].getAttribute("data-type")) {
        
      case 'pants':      
      case 'shirts':
        inputs[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
          if (e.target.checked) {
            addElement(e.target);
          } else {
            document.getElementById(e.target.name).remove();
          }
        })
        
        if (inputs[i].checked) {
          addElement(inputs[i]);
        }
        break;
        
    }
  }
})

function addElement(t) {
  var vals = t.getAttribute('data-text').split('|');
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.type = "text";
  input.value = vals[0];
  input.name = vals[1];
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.id = t.name;
  div.innerHTML = vals[2];
  div.appendChild(input);
  document.getElementById(vals[3]).appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<p>Clothing</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" checked data-type="pants" 
       data-text="1|AmountPants|Amount of pants: |pantsinput" />Pants
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check2" data-type="shirts" 
       data-text="2|AmountShirts|Amount of shirts: |shirtinput" />Shirt
<br>

<p id="pantsinput"></p>
<p id="shirtinput"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the effort.

Comment: @Brayn Glad it helped

Answer (score 1):

You have registered `PantsInput` on the click of your checkbox which means it won't work automatically until you click it. So to make it happen you must have to call it forcefully.

```
if($Pants=="1"){
   echo "<input type='checkbox' onclick='PantsInput(this);' name='checkbox1' checked>Pants<br>";
   echo "<script>PantsInput(document.getElementsByName('checkbox1')[0])</script>";
}
else {
   echo "<input type='checkbox'> Pants<br>";
}
```

Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve your problem is to set up a means by which the events that you're listening for, in order to generate the `<input>` elements, are fired on page-load. To do that, all you have to add is the following:

```
// creating the event that we're listening for:
var clickEvent = new Event('click');

// using document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked')
// to return the nodeList of <input> elements whose 'type' attribute
// is equal to 'checkbox' which are also checked, and passing that
// nodeList to Array.from() to convert the Array-like nodeList into
// an Array, allowing us to use Array methods:
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked'))

  // Array.prototype.forEach() allows us to iterate over every node
  // in the Array of nodes:
  .forEach(function(input){
  // 'input': a reference to the current <input> element in the
  // Array of <input> elements over which we're iterating.

    // firing the clickEvent (created above) from the <input>
    // element, causing the event-handler to be fired:
    input.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
  });
```

```js
function PantsInput(cbox) {
  if (cbox.checked) {
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    input.value = "1";
    input.name = "AmountPants"
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = cbox.name;
    div.innerHTML = "Amount of pants: ";
    div.appendChild(input);
    document.getElementById("pantsinput").appendChild(div);
  } else if (document.getElementById(cbox.name)) {
    document.getElementById(cbox.name).remove();
  }
}

function ShirtInput(cbox) {
  if (cbox.checked) {
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    input.value = "2";
    input.name = "AmountShirt"
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = cbox.name;
    div.innerHTML = "Amount of shirts: ";
    div.appendChild(input);
    document.getElementById("shirtinput").appendChild(div);
  } else if (document.getElementById(cbox.name)) {
    document.getElementById(cbox.name).remove();
  }
}

var clickEvent = new Event('click');
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input'))
  .forEach(function(input) {
    input.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
  });
```

```html
<p>Clothing</p>
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" checked onclick="PantsInput(this);" />Pants
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check2" onclick="ShirtInput(this);" />Shirt
<br>

<p id="pantsinput"></p>
<p id="shirtinput"></p>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/orqweyzc/1/).

Note that, because we're iterating over elements in the DOM, this code has to run *after* the elements are created, and present in the DOM, which is most easily achieved by placing the `<script>` just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Now, while the problem is superficially solved, you're still left with two identical functions, so if we can refactor that to use the same function to produce slightly different results, based on the element that was checked, that should make more sense.

Also, using in-line event-handlers is considered bad practice, and 'obtrusive JavaScript,' which makes it harder for you, and for those maintaining the code in future, when you need to update. Further, we'll associate beside the `<input>` elements with the `<input>` elements, using a `<label>`.

So, in the following, we'll use JavaScript to bind the event-handlers and we'll refactor the code so that we only use the one function:

```
// using a single named function (the name of which tries to
// convey the functionality):
function amountsOf() {

  // caching the 'this' (passed automatically from the
  // EventTarget.addEventListener() method (later in
  // the code):
  var changed = this,

  // caching the textContent of the <input> element's
  // parentNode (the <label> element), with the leading
  // and trailing white-space removed courtesy of
  // String.prototype.trim():
    inputName = changed.parentNode.textContent.trim(),

  // creating a new <input> element:
    input = document.createElement("input"),

  // creating a new <label> element:
    label = document.createElement('label'),

  // creating text for the <label> element, via the creation
  // of a new TextNode:
    text = document.createTextNode("Amount of " + inputName + ": "),

  // finding the element to which the content should be
  // appended, or from which it should be removed:
    contentTo = document.getElementById(inputName.toLowerCase() + 'input');

  // if the current <input> element is checked:
  if (changed.checked) {

    // we append the textNode to the <label>:
    label.appendChild(text);

    // then append the <input> to the <label>:
    label.appendChild(input);

    // setting the type property/attribute of the <input>:    
    input.type = "text";

    // setting the current value of the <input> from the
    // (valid) custom data-inputvalue attribute added to
    // the <input>, though honestly I don't think this
    // adds any benefit to the user of the site:
    input.value = changed.dataset.inputvalue;

    // setting the <input> element's name property:
    input.name = "Amount" + inputName;

    // appending the <label> to the element to which
    // content should be added:
    contentTo.appendChild(label);
  } else {

    // finding the <label> element within the <p>
    // to which content was added, and removing
    // it:
    contentTo.querySelector('label').remove();
  }
}

// using document.querySelectorAll() to find all <input>
// elements of type=checkbox, and passing that nodeList
// to Array.from(), to convert the Array-like NodeList
// into an Array, to enable the use of Array methods:
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]'))

  // her we use Array.forEach() to iterate over the Array of
  // <input> elements, using an Arrow function syntax;
  // 'input' is a reference to the current <input> node of 
  // the Array, and we then pass that to the Arrow function,
  // which binds the amountsOf() function (though note the
  // deliberate absence of parentheses) as the 'change'
  // event-handler for the current <input> element:
  .forEach(input => input.addEventListener('change', amountsOf))


// here we create a new Event, in order to fire the named
// 'change' event on those elements that have the checked
// attribute/property:
var changeEvent = new Event('change');

// here we create an Array of all the <input> elements of
// type=checkbox, which are currently checked:
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked'))

  // we iterate over that Array of elements using the
  // anonymous method (though we could use an Arrow
  // function instead):
  .forEach(function(input) {
    // 'input' is a reference to the current <input>
    // element in the array of <input> elements over
    // which we're currently iterating:

    // here we fire the 'change' event on those
    // found checked <input> elements:
    input.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
  });
```

```js
function amountsOf() {
  var changed = this,
    inputName = changed.parentNode.textContent.trim(),
    input = document.createElement("input"),
    label = document.createElement('label'),
    text = document.createTextNode("Amount of " + inputName + ": "),
    contentTo = document.getElementById(inputName.toLowerCase() + 'input');
  if (changed.checked) {
    label.appendChild(text);
    label.appendChild(input);

    input.type = "text";
    input.value = changed.dataset.inputvalue;
    input.name = "Amount" + inputName;

    document.getElementById(inputName.toLowerCase() + 'input').appendChild(label);

  } else {
    contentTo.querySelector('label').remove();
  }
}

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]'))
  .forEach(input => input.addEventListener('change', amountsOf))


var changeEvent = new Event('change');
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked'))
  .forEach(function(input) {
    input.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
  });
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>Clothing</p>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check1" data-inputvalue="1" checked />Pants</label>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check2" data-inputvalue="2" />Shirts</label>

<p id="pantsinput"></p>
<p id="shirtsinput"></p>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/orqweyzc/3/).

Note that there were some changes to both your HTML, and to your JavaScript function.

To the html we wrapped the `<input>` elements in `<label>` elements, so that a click on the `<label>` element's text would focus, or change, the associated `<input>` element (for a better user-interface). I updated the `id` of the 'shirts' paragraph, from 'shirtinput' to 'shirtsinput,' simply to maintain consistency of the `id` structrure, since we're using only the one function. This also makes semantic sense, given that presumably the user may want to select multiple shirts.

In the JavaScript function I've removed the `<div>` element entirely, since a `<div>` cannot be a child of a `<p>` element, and the created `<input>` element is now wrapped in a `<label>` anyway.

Also, rather than hard-code the values of the newly-created `<input>` elements in the JavaScript I've moved those values into custom `data-*` attributes within the HTML, the `data-inputvalue` attributes. While I've maintained your values, and their insertion, I'm genuinely unsure as to what benefit this offers the user; surely the default should be `1` or `0` given that the number of shirts, or pants, is entirely up to them (I'd argue that `1` is likely the better option, otherwise they're unlikely to have clicked the `<input>` in the first place).

References:

- CSS:

  - [Attribute selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors).
  - [`:checked` pseudo class](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#checked).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
  - [`ChildNode.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/appendChild).
  - [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).
  - [`document.createTextNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Event()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
  - [`EventTarget.dispatchEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent).
  - [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).
  - [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).
  - [`Node.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode).

Bibliography:

- "[Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)."